# Listview column header names, stackable?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm just curious as to if the column names are stackable on top of each other, in other words:

ORIGINAL

```
|test|testing test1|testing test32|test3|
```

NEW

```
|test|testing|testing|test
       test1  test32
```

I know it's possible to do in a gridview but I  like to stay away from them when i have the chance.  I've currently got around 10 columns and would love to not have to implement a horizontal scroll bar if I don't have to.

Comment: you're asking if you can change the rowheight of just the column header row in a listview control?  I'm not seeing any properties like listview.columnHeaderHeight.  Looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the default ListView,

I found another post where Grammarian shared a link to a custom listview control you could use for your purposes. As i look thru the screenshots it might fit into your requirements, check it out :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

The post i got it from is :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461601/setting-height-of-listview-row

Good Luck !